# How to hide navbar in Ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to hide  in Ionic 2. I tried `<ion-navbar [hidden]="true">` but it is not working.

Can anyone please tell me how to conditionally hide navbar in ionic2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a property from your component to hide/show it

```
<ion-navbar *ngIf="showNavbar">
```

And in your component code:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
  public showNavbar: boolean;

  // ...

  public hideNavbar(): void {
    this.showNavbar = false;

    // You should resize the content to use the space left by the navbar
    this.content.resize();
  }
}
```